# Insertion sort script on powershell

Tags: algorithm, powershell, sorting, scripting

I am trying to make insertion sort algorithm in case of studying on powershell.

Code:

```
$TestArrayList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@(8, 2, 11, 12, 5, 6, 7)

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $TestArrayList.Count; $i++) {

    $key = $TestArrayList[$i]

    $j = $i-1

    while($j -gt 0 -and $key -lt $TestArrayList[$j]){

        $TestArrayList[$j+1] = $TestArrayList[$j] 
        $TestArrayList[$j] = $key
        $j = $j-1

       #Write-Output $TestArrayList[$i]

    }

    Write-Output $TestArrayList[$i]
}
```

Output of the code is next:

```
8
2
11
12
12
12
12
```

Can you please help me to analyze, what's the problem. I tried to make it sorted from small to bigger one.

Expected to be sorted:

```
2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code right now:

- The output is not the finally sorted list, it's intermediate output from the `Write-Output` statement.
- There's an off-by-one bug in the nested `while` loop that'll cause the first item to always be ignored.

To fix the first issue, simply remove the `Write-Output` statement from the loop.

To fix the second issue, change the first comparison in the `while` condition to `$j -ge 0` instead of `$j -gt 0`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $TestArrayList.Count; $i++) {

    $key = $TestArrayList[$i]

    $j = $i - 1

    while($j -ge 0 -and $key -lt $TestArrayList[$j]){

        $TestArrayList[$j+1] = $TestArrayList[$j] 
        $TestArrayList[$j] = $key
        $j = $j - 1
    }
}

# the list is now sorted correctly
$TestArrayList
```